# Why can't qt/qmake find my shared library

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

I am trying to create and application to cross compile with the raspberry pi 3. Originally I just had a project named "application" and everything worked great. Knowing the scope of the project I thought it would be a good idea to abstract out the classes I am bound to add. So I turned the project into a subdirs project. That is were the issues started.

The directory looks like this

```
IntegratedSmartHome.pro       subdirs
-->Application.pro            app
-->Libs.pro                   subdirs
---->common.pro               library
```

I followed [this guide](https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_create_a_library_with_Qt_and_use_it_in_an_application) and a couple of dozen others looking for guidance and none was found.

The error I am getting is:

```
10:37:03: Starting /home/jesse/Projects/build-integratedSmartHome-Desktop_Qt_5_11_1_GCC_64bit-Debug/application/application...
/home/jesse/Projects/build-integratedSmartHome-Desktop_Qt_5_11_1_GCC_64bit-Debug/application/application: error while loading shared libraries: libcommon.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
10:37:03: /home/jesse/Projects/build-integratedSmartHome-Desktop_Qt_5_11_1_GCC_64bit-Debug/application/application exited with code 127
```

Picture of libs folder after build

[image]

Any guidance on how to fix this would be appreciated! I will include my 4 .pro files below. *note: I get no build errors*

**IntegratedSmartHome.pro:**

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs

SUBDIRS += \
    libs \
    application

application.depends = libs

CONFIG += ordered
```

**Application.pro**

```
QT += gui quick
CONFIG += c++11

DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    smartdevicesmodel.cpp \
    globalproperties.cpp

HEADERS += \
    smartdevicesmodel.h \
    globalproperties.h

RESOURCES += \
        res/res.qrc

INCLUDEPATH += ../libs/common

LIBS += \
    -L../libs/common -lcommon

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

**Libs.pro**

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs

SUBDIRS += \
    common

CONFIG += ordered
```

**Common.pro**

```
QT -= gui

CONFIG += c++11
CONFIG -= app_bundle

DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    devicetype.cpp \
    smartdevice.cpp

HEADERS += \
    devicetype.h \
    smartdevice.h

! include( ../libs.pri ) {
    error( "Couldn't find the libs.pri file!" )
}

# Default rules for deployment.
#qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
#else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
#!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

**Libs.pri**

```
INCLUDEPATH += . ..
WARNINGS += -Wall

TEMPLATE = lib

UI_DIR = uics
MOC_DIR = mocs
OBJECTS_DIR = objs
```

**EDIT:**
I have a little experience writing build shell scripts, if you think it is worth my time, or that it won't be too difficult to continue to support the raspi with one of those, I could try that and then I would be a little more explicit with linking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a build failure, judging by the log output you posted. This is a runtime failure, because the loader can't find the shared library. It can't find the shared library because it is not on the default `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (or as configured via `/etc/ld.so.conf`).

To run your application you probably want to edit the run configuration in the IDE to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to point to the folder with your `libcommon.so` in it.

Comment: That fixed my issue. For reference for others, I went into the "Project" tab on qt creator and added the library path to my common.so files to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH in the run time environment variables list.